# Neoload - post json content type

Tags: json, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing, neoload

I want to post json content type for my post request in Neoload.
I can see json is not listed under Post content type dropdown.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chose "Text" as the content type and paste your JSON content.